# Selecting multiple value in select tag using an error

Tags: php, html

I have an array and select multiple fields. What I am trying to do is whenever the file load all the select option will get selected using the array ID. My array is

> Array( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 )

And what my select field is:

```
<select id="selSkills"  name="selSkills[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <?php 
    $myArray = explode(',',$empInfo[0]['skills']);
    $skillSQL_count = COUNT($skillInfo); 
    for($i=0; $i<$skillSQL_count; $i++) {   ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'];?>" <?php if($skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'] == $myArray[$i]) { echo "selected"; }  ?>><?php echo $skillInfo[$i]['skill_name'];?></option>
    <?php }  ?>
</select>
```

But somehow I am getting an array

> PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED Severity Undefined Offset 3

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if($skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'] == $myArray[$i])
```

use

```
if(in_array($skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'], $myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You also did,

```
<?php
    $myArray = isset($empInfo[0]['skills']) ? explode(',',$empInfo[0]['skills']) : [];
    $select = '<select id="selSkills"  name="selSkills[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>';
    if (!empty($myArray)) {
        foreach ((array)$myArray as $key => $value) {
            $select .= '<option
                                value="'.(isset($skillInfo[$i]['skill_id']) ? $skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'] : 0).'"
                                '.(isset($skillInfo[$i]['skill_id']) && $skillInfo[$i]['skill_id'] == $value ? "selected" : "").'>
                                '.(isset($skillInfo[$i]['skill_name']) ? $skillInfo[$i]['skill_name'] : '')
                       .'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $select .= '<option value="0">No record found !</option>';
    }
    $select .= '<select>';
    echo $select;
?>
```